# How do I properly make an IgnoreCollision command?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the code to where is resets when my main object hits another object. However it hits every single object and resets the scene. I'm attempting to make my main abject ignore a certain object. Here is what I have so far.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
       SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "BlueLaunchpad")
        {
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(BlueLaunchpad.collider); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `However it hits every single object and resets the scene` and what are you talking about here? Is this `Unity`?

Comment: Please add the Unity tag. It seems you're using their API

Comment: You're doing this wrong! if (collision.gameObject.tag == "RightObject")
        {
Doaction();
}

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try something like thins:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider collider )
{       
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "BlueLaunchpad")
    {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(collider); 
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

this way it shouldn't load the scene when it hits the BlueLaunchpad

Comment: Everything works except in (BlueLaunchPad.collider);  It gives me an error on BlueLaunchPad.   I think im missing something but im not sure what. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sory, i haven't run the program my self, try Physics.IgnoreCollision(collider);  i have edited the anser